# Ubuntu server wont respond to any requests (ssh, telnet, ping, etc)

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, ssh, tcpdump

I am relatively new to things like this so please bear with me.

OS info:

PC - Arch Linux (5.10.67-1-lts)

RPi - Ubuntu Server (20.04.3 LTS)

About a week ago I set up a small Samba NAS server on a raspberry pi. However, this morning the server suddenly stopped responding to any requests, which all time out (I've tried ping, telnet, ssh, etc.). I rebooted the server which did not help. I also restarted ssh on both the server and the client.

I ran `tcpdump -vv -i eth0 port 22 -n -Q inout` on the server (through direct keyboard connection), but when I tried connecting to the pi through ssh again, `tcpdump` did not display anything on the server. I tried the reverse of this (same `tcpdump` command on my PC and ssh from the server), and `tcpdump` displayed this response on my computer:

`18:10:06.923088 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 33674, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)`

`server-ip.60284 > computer-ip.22: Flags [S], cksum 0xda46 (correct), seq 2610540948, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3534156811 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0`

(Not sure what most of this means)

Even with this output, ssh still timed out on the server. `telnet computer-ip 22` also gives the exact same output.

I checked logs and IP blacklists on the server and found nothing.

I am trying to connect to the pi through a direct ethernet connection (network switch not connected to router), so I don't think the issue should be related to my router or a lack of an internet connection. I have also temporarily tried disabling ufw, which did not help. Although I don't think this issue is firewall related (because turning it off didn't help), I will provide my relevant configurations anyways.

Here is my ufw configuration for my pc:

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         LIMIT       Anywhere                  
25                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
1725/udp                   ALLOW       Anywhere                 
CIFS                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
137                        ALLOW       Anywhere                  
138                        ALLOW       Anywhere                  
139                        ALLOW       Anywhere                  
445                        ALLOW       Anywhere                  
631                        ALLOW       Anywhere

(DEFAULT OUTBOUND: ALLOW)
(DEFAULT INBOUND: DENY)
```

And for my server:

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     LIMIT       Anywhere                 
Samba                      ALLOW       Anywhere                  
137                        ALLOW       Anywhere                  
138                        ALLOW       Anywhere                  
139                        ALLOW       Anywhere                  
445                        ALLOW       Anywhere                  
631                        ALLOW       Anywhere

(DEFAULT OUTBOUND: ALLOW)
(DEFAULT INBOUND: DENY)
```

Any help is appreciated and I am happy to provide any other information. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I figured it out. When attempting to post this question, superuser blocked it due to spam coming from my network. I remembered I was on a VPN, and realized very quickly that my inability to connect to my home server was likely due to that. Turning off the VPN fixed the issue with posting this question and connection to my NAS server.

Thought I would answer the question in case anyone else makes the same silly mistake.